# Using the division operation in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Someone wrote the following select statement:

```
select ... ,   FLOOR (a / b) AS c, ...
```

You can tell a problem of the select statement. If b is zero, the query will lead to an exception.

How to place a condition here so that if b is zero, the c will yeild zero as well?

**Update:**

A case statement can be used to sovle this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037), where you can control the value and avoid the exception.

```
select ..., CASE WHEN b IS 0 THEN 0 ELSE (a / b) END AS c, ...
```

Comment: That is an appreach I use.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nullif()`:

```
select ... , FLOOR(a / NULLIF(b, 0)) AS c, ...
```

I much prefer having `NULL` as in the unknown value.  If you want `0`, you can use:

```
select ... , COALESCE(FLOOR(a / NULLIF(b, 0)), 0) AS c, ...
```

Of course, this assumes that neither `a` nor `b` are `NULL` themselves.

Comment: Not sure that is what I need as "The NULLIF() function returns NULL if two expressions are equal, otherwise it returns the first expression."

Comment: Didn't know you could use `NULLIF()` with a single argument. Doesn't it require two?

Comment: @TheImpaler Added :)

Comment: I test the above on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_nullif It would return nothing if b = 0.

Comment: @vw_tsc You could wrap the whole expression in a `case`/`nvl`/`decode` expression. However, as the result of dividing by zero is normally meaningless, a null value is a more common requirement than returning zero.